# Eliminate an object whose properties assigned to NULL while rendering API data

Tags: reactjs, api, error-handling

I have fetched the below data from an API but out of 10 objects 1 object has multiple properties assigned to NULL. [API fetched data screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSPgH.png) 
While rendering these objects with properties it is throwing an error of "cannot read properties of NULL(reading 'value')" . Here is my code:

```
const Home = () => {
    const [movies, setMovies] =useState([]);
  useEffect(()=>{
      const fetchData =async()=>{  
    try{
        const  {data} = await axios.get("https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=all")
        setMovies(data)
        console.log(data)
    }
    catch{

    }
  }
    fetchData() 
      
  },[])

  return (
    <div className="movieCards-container ">


      <h1 className="heading"> Recommended Movies</h1>
      <div className=" container-custom d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center pb-5 ">
        <div className="row justify-content-center">
        {movies.map((item,index) => {
          return (
            <div className=" col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center ">
            <MovieCard 
            key={item.show.id}
            id={item.show.id} 
            name={item.show.name} 
            image={item.show.image.original} 
            rating={item.show.rating.average}
            showday={item.show.schedule.days}
            showtime={item.show.schedule.time}
            
            />
      </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I want to render all other objects except the one with properties assigned to NULL.

Comment: Tangential: It’s better to include the JSON as formatted code. Copy-pasting a `util.inspect` *(with a suitable depth)* is easier to deal with 

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform a conditional render of the component.

So just do:

```
{movies.map((item,index) => { return (
            <div className=" col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center ">
            {item && <MovieCard //this is the line that will check for null and prevent anything further from happening in case of null
            key={item.show.id}
            id={item.show.id}
    .../>})})
```

Of course it's still better to do optional chaining everywhere to prevent this sort of error in case a single field is missing ex. item?.show?.id

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need is to use ternary operator.

Link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator

This way you can conditionally send the parameter to your component.
You check first if something exists, and if it does exist. Use it. If not send a placeholder for example.

Example:

{item.show.image ? item.show.image.original : 'placeholder'}

Here I check if the "item.show.image" exists. If it does I use the "item.show.image.original". If not. I render "placeholder".

I hope it will help you. :)